# unable to fetch json data from api on live server

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, php-8.2

I am unable to fetch JSON data from API using curl on the live server. everything is working fine on localhost & I am able to fetch data on localhost with the following code...

```
$keyword = $insertedtemplate->search_query;
  $apiUrl = 'https://api.envato.com/v1/discovery/search/search/item?page=1&page_size='.$num_items.'&site=themeforest.net&sort_by=sales&sort_direction=desc&term='.$keyword;
  $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer RITWou6mrLVsj84Y2Ofc2eS3v*******";  

  $curl = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
  $result = curl_exec($curl); 
  curl_close($curl);
  $data = json_decode($result);
  dd($data);
```

getting `null` error on the live server.

Comment: We don't know what "unable to" means. If the code works in one environment, then it generally doesn't give us much of a clue about what goes wrong when you use it in another one. What debugging have you done? Have you turned on curl's verbose logging, or tried in any other way to see what happens to the request? Maybe the request fails? Maybe it success but the data returned is just different than you expected? We have no idea, and we have no way to know - we can't run the code. Please clarify the situation. We can help you, but only if you provide useful information about the issue. See [ask]